# I can't install cgi module in wamp

Tags: python, apache, wamp, httpd.conf

I can't install cgi to my server. I tried to change the httpd.conf file and I couldn't do it. 
The message is

> Not Found The requested URL /cgi-bin/ was not found on this server.

I change the next lines in the httpd.conf file

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride All
Options +ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Can you explain what goes wrong ?

Comment: Do you have folder `"C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/cgi-bin/"` on disk ?

Comment: yes ! I wrote this path